# Design fail, abuse of MDC

Tags: java

I had to take over an giant monolith with several layers, services and components.

While i was walking over the code, first thing I realize is the use of [MDC](http://slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html).

Some example:

```
public void setContextOrderId(String orderId) {
    MDC.put("orderId", orderId);
}
```

or

```
String sessionId = MDC.get("sessionId");
```

MDC is used as a static HashMap across the app, I beleive the motive was due to the fact that MDC is available per request across the request pipeline and it was used as a storage.

How can I replace it? Is there an alternative for thread safe container?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Oh my. Someone used MDC for data storage. "Abuse" is the correct term here.

The correct solution depends on what exactly is used. For instance if you run something like Spring, that would probably be something like request-scope beans.

Technically, most "request scope" solutions use [`ThreadLocal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) under the hood. `MDC` also uses `ThreadLocal`.

If I wer to refactor something like that, I'd try to move in the direction of some dependency injection container which respects different scopes (request, session, application etc.), be it Spring or whatever else. If you just replace `MDC` with your own `ThreadLocal`-based storage you won't win much.

Comment: it just bothers me why MDC is used for a storage. Every bit of data is put and read from MDC all over the place.